# How to maintain text formating while performing copy-paste action in powerpoint using vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In my last question "[Find number from text in powerpoint using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098276/find-number-from-text-in-powerpoint-using-vba)", I made a code & its working perfectly (thanks to **Tony Dallimore**). But in this process i am facing some unexpected things like :

1. If my textbox contain text with bullets & sub bullets.
2. If it contains http links with some font color.

Then after running my code. it shows me data without any text formatting like above specified text formatting is vanish.

Now i know why this happen. Because in my code i collect all text into one variable & then perform action and then replace it to the old one in ppt.

So my question "Is there any way to run code within the textbox, so mentioned problem will be solved?"

For code please go to [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098276/find-number-from-text-in-powerpoint-using-vba).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

more of a hint than an answer:

range objects have a ".duplicate" property - which copies the formatting. See if this can be applied to your scenario.

eg.

create a new document. Format the first paragraph in a way that pleases you. then:

```
set dup = ActiveDocument.Paragraph(1).Format.Duplicate

Documents.Add
Selection.InsertAfter "This is a new paragraph."
Selection.Paragraphs.Format = dup
```

the text in the new page will be formatted as before

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer how it works? please give me one example